# Which child process will accept the connection?

Tags: linux, network-programming

There is a server listening on a socket which then forks multiple fixed number of children (say 5).

Each child then blocks on accept() call.

I am working on proxy server that should handle thousands of simultaneous connections.So I fork multiple 
children for accepting connections.This is not similar to when a child is forked for each connections.

When a client connects to the server, how does kernel decide which child process will get this connection?

Is there a specific algorithm(round robin, least connections etc.) that kernel follows when taking this decision ?

Comment: You should not do that. Use `AF_UNIX` sockets (or pipes, or FIFOs), and have each child accepting on its own socket. Sockets are cheaper than child processes. You'll typically have at most a dozen of children processes.

Comment: you mean [Thundering herd problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem)?

Comment: Thundering Herd Problem does not exist on modern kernels.